# how do I release these encrypted pfiles?

Tags: azure-information-protection

Somehow, I do not know how, I have managed to invoke this Microsoft Azure Information Management lock on, I guess, my user directory.  I just want to undo it. How do I get rid of all these .pfiles, .ptxt, .pjpg, [p]pdf, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using PowerShell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azureinformationprotection/unprotect-rmsfile?view=azureipps

Something recursive like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | if((Get-AIPFileStatus -File $_.Fullname).IsRMSProtected) { Unprotect-RMSFile -File $_.FullName
```

I haven't tested that, but it looks like it'll work on paper.